# Проблемы с Gradle на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gradle

После установки gradle я столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
>   Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().

Следовал инструкции сайта:http://itisgood.ru/2019/03/05/kak-ustanovit-gradle-na-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04/
Я только изучаю gradle и поэтому ничего не понимаю еще.Помогите люди добрые!

Comment: Покажите свой `build.gradle`

Comment: @Barmaley Red StarГде его найти?

Comment: В корне проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!Извините за беспокойство!Проблема решилась простым удалением,перезагрузкой и повторным скачиванием.Подскажите пожалуйста какие книги(желательно на русском) или сайт вы советуете мне прочитать,чтобы освоить gradle(хотя бы на базовом уровне).Прочитав пару статей в интернете я ничего не понял от слова совсем.Пишут для тех, кто уже что-то да знает в этом деле.Я пишу на java в eclipse под управлением Ubuntu.Всем буду очень благодарен!

Comment: странно, что на украинском нет никакой документации по gradle...